# SwiftUI: How to have a ForEach of editable TextFields?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to have a component that basically starts with a single TextField for editing your home phone number, and then you can hit the add button to add different types of phone numbers to your account. for right now I just want to allow the user to edit the phone number, but in the future I'll probably make it so that there are actually two TextFields for each PhoneNumberListItem. 1 field for the editable name and 1 field for the editable phone itself. I'm coming from Android/Compose which is maybe where my line of thinking is stuck. appreciate any pointers.

```
func ListOfMyPhoneNumbers() -> some View {
    @State var listOfMyPhones = [PhoneNumberListItem(name: "home", phone: "123")]
    
    return VStack {
        ForEach(listOfMyPhones) { i in
            TextField(i.name, text: i.$phone).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    }
        Button("Add Phone") {
            listOfMyPhones.append(PhoneNumberListItem(name: "other", phone: ""))
            
        }.buttonStyle(.borderless)
        
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
}


struct PhoneNumberListItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    @State var phone: String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `@State var phone: String` in your `PhoneNumberListItem`.
`@State` is only for use in a `View`. Just use a `var`.

Also use a `struct` for your view. With the following example code you will be able to edit the `TextField` in a `ForEach`, like this:

```
struct PhoneNumberListItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String   // <--- here
    var phone: String  // <--- here
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PhoneView()  // <--- here
    }
}

struct PhoneView: View {  // <--- here
    @State var listOfMyPhones = [PhoneNumberListItem(name: "home", phone: "123")]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // --- here
            ForEach($listOfMyPhones) { $item in
                TextField("phone", text: $item.phone)
                TextField("name", text: $item.name)
            }.textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)

            Button("Add Phone") {
                listOfMyPhones.append(PhoneNumberListItem(name: "other", phone: ""))
            }.buttonStyle(.borderless)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

As you progress with learning SwiftUI, you will want to use `ObservableObject` class to manage your data. Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: thanks for not making me feel dumb. looks like i was pretty close to getting it off the docs/examples. thanks @workingdog